# jboss-eap-6.3 - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jboss/modules/Main (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)

Tags: java, unix, jboss-eap-6

i have installed jboss-eap-6.3 on UNIX server, when i run the `add-user.sh` script i am getting following error..

```
jboss-eap-6.3/bin $ ./add-user.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jboss/modules/Main (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:539)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:123)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:55)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:187)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:289)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:274)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:235)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:302)
```

Comment: This error occurs when you compile you code with a different version of java and execute it with another one. Check the possibilities of compiling your classes

Comment: @VivekSingh i am not compiling any code, i am installing jboss on UNIX server

Comment: @GirdharSinghRathore what is the version of JDK in Unix machine

Comment: @ankur-singhal java version "1.6.0_91"

Comment: @GirdharSinghRathore code compiled on which version..??

Comment: @ankur-singhal both are same javac 1.6.0_91

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The message about version 50.0 means that the class files were
>   compiled for JDK 1.6 (or greater, when others are released). The JVM
>   that's reading that file must not be 1.6.

**Compile in JDK 1.6 and running on lower version than Java 6**

Please refer [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/417240/java/java/Unsupported-major-minor-version) for similar kind of issue.

Comment: Thanks ankur, problem is solved, my variable JAVA_HOME was pointing to j2sdk1.4.2_16 , but it require jdk1.6.0_16 or above

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the version of Java you are using?
You have to know that JBoss EAP 6.x must be run on JDK 6 or JDK 7.